# How to split one very long line in Pycharm into multiple lines?

Tags: python, pycharm

After parsing, I've got a lot of urls that have unfortunately joined together in one line. It will take a long time to re-parse, so I ask if there is a method as one long line with Url to turn into a multiple lines - 1 Url per line?

What i have:

```
'https:// url1.com/bla1','https:// url1.com/bla2',..thousands of urls..,'https:// url999.com/blaN'
```

What i need:

```
'https:// url1.com/bla-1',
'https:// url1.com/bla-2',
etc
'https:// url999.com/bla-N'
```

I've already tried to uncheck Line breaks in Python - Wrapping and Braces and check Ensure right margin is not exceeded - doesn't work

So how can i fix it?

Comment: What is the actual starting input string?  Did you forget to put double quotes around it?

Comment: @Mark : mention the data-type. Is that a  tuple???

Comment: Mark the line, hit cmd+r and replace `,` by `,\n` with ticks in `Regex` and `Selection` might be a work around.

Comment: The output file contains 'url', 'url2', 'urlN' without spaces and anything else

Comment: One very long line

Comment: but to be readable, I want to split it into multiple lines (one line with 200,000 urls into 200,000 lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try a simple method, if I understand your query correctly. Read the first file, replace commas with newline character, and write the result to the same file.

```
urlsfile = open('test1.txt', 'r+') # in case you are getting the data from file itself
urls = urlsfile.readline()
urlsfile.close()
newlines = urls.replace(",", "\n") # otherwise replace newlines with the variable name that you are trying to write to the file
newfile = open('test1.txt','w+')
newfile.write(newlines)
newfile.close()
```

Comment: Sorry that i didn't answer and thank you for answering for me.

Comment: I did the same thing - with('urls.txt', 'r') as f:

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
First set `Code->Style->Wrapping and Braces->Method parameters/Method call arguments` to `wrap if long` or `chop down if long.`
After that simply call reformat code on the line `(Command+Alt+L).`

Comment: But this just wrap the lines when exceeding the max line length and not after each value, does it?

Comment: Yes, lines exceeding the max length will be split into multiple lines. This is what OP has asked.

Comment: I havent chop down if long \ wrap if long in Method call arguments =(

Comment: The line still doesn't split into multiple lines =(

Comment: try changing the value for `hard wrap at :` from 120 to 60.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted

Comment: It can take half the url of the previous one and throw it on a new line

Comment: are all urls of the same length.. if so, then hard wrap the text at the length of the url +1...hope it works.

Comment: I basically wrote a program that changes the " ,'https " to " , + \n + 'https in the file))

Comment: I'll drop it later as an answer for me

Comment: @Mark Sure...Go on